# Чем отличается merge от commit?

Tags: svn

Чем отличается merge от commit?
Когда комитим - заливаем, скажем, в главную ветку свои изменения. Когда мержим - объединяем  свою копию с изменениями в главной ветке.

Когда нужно выложить проект в продакшн, переключаемся на trunk, мержим, а потом еще и комитим, зачем второе действие?

Comment: @nMike, все *очень* просто. "Meржим" всегда **свою** копию, база не меняется. "Коммитим" - это *заливаем свое* **в базу**. 

Насколько помню, если при commit возникает конфликт, то commit не проходит. Надо сделать svn merge в локальную копию, разрешить конфликты, а
потом закинуть в базу svn ci .

Comment: тогда чем отличается merge от update?

Comment: @nMike А чем отличается зеленый от сладкого?

Comment: Мержим из транка, апдейтим из ветки. Если работаем в транке, то операции эквивалентны.

Comment: @nMike вы ошибаетесь, merge от update отличаются не только этим.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы `merge` был бы эквивалентен `merge + commit`, то пользователь потерял бы возможность выполнять следующие действия:

> - Целиком `review'ить` изменения в `feature branch`, которые появляются после `merge --reintegrate`.
> - Решать `conflict'ы` и `tree conflict'ы`, которые возникли в результате операции `merge`.

Answer (score 2):

- **Commit** - означает выложить свою версию в репозиторий
- **Update** - означает выкачать версию из репозитория (обновить свою)
- **Merge** - означает внесение изменений в своей версии по сравнению
  с версией из репозитория. Обычно юзеру предоставляется возможность
  просмотра изменений (построчно) чтобы определить какие изменения из 
  репо можно применить к своей версии (решение конфликтов).
- **Diff** - сравнение 2-х версий. Часто имеет смысл делать перед **Merge** 
  или для просмотра изменений сделанных другим членом команды
- **Checkout** - выкачивание целиком исходников из репо. Как правило делается
  в самом начале работы

Типовой паттерн работы такой: checkout → работаем → commit → перерыв → update (возможно с merge) → работаем → commit и т.д.

Comment: У тебя merge и commit получаются одинаковыми операциями. Надо уточнять, что merge надо использовать при работе с ветками, чтобы в свою ветку скачать то, что выложили в trunk.

Comment: @nMike прочтите внимательнее :)

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что commit - это не просто заливка изменений. Сущность этой операции заключается в том, что изменения, сделанные локально, преобразуются в изменения, которые могут быть успешно добавлены в репозиторий и зафиксированы в нём в виде очередной ревизии. При этом локальные изменения всегда выражены в виде различий относительно последней ревизии, о которой известно локально (т.е. ревизии, которая была во время последнего update), а в репозиторий могут быть добавлены лишь такие изменения, которые выражены в виде различий относительно последней ревизии самого репозитория.

В простейшем случае, когда в репозиторий не было добавлено ничего со стороны, преобразование изменений сводится к тому, чтобы не делать ничего, поскольку изменения и так уже выражены в виде различий относительно последней ревизии в репозитории. Поэтому операция commit становится тривиальной и выглядит, как простая заливка изменений. В случае же, когда с момента последнего update в репозитории уже появилось что-то новое, попытка сделать тривиальный commit проваливается и приходится проходить всю процедуру полностью, т.е. сначала приспосабливать свои локальные изменения к тем другим изменениям, которые уже были зафиксированы в репозитории кем-то другим, и только потом заливать их и фиксировать.

Когда мы заливаем в репозиторий изменения, сделанные в рабочей копии, необходимость делать commit в самом конце очевидна. Ведь в репозитории ещё нет наших локальных изменений, поскольку предыдущая попытка сделать тривиальный commit провалилась. Не так очевидна эта необходимость в ситуации, когда мы объединяем одну ветку с другой прямо в репозитории с помощью merge. Дело тут вот в чём. На самом деле, операция commit играет ещё и роль подтверждения. Заливка в репозиторий новых изменений как в тривиальном случае, так и после адаптации всегда выполняется после того, как пользователь увидел окончательный вариант, поэтому его подтверждение, необходимое для фиксации очередной ревизии, как бы подразумевается и даётся тем же самым commit'ом. А вот про объединение веток в репозитории такого сказать нельзя. Результат объединения веток обычно отличается от того, что было в последних ревизиях как одной ветки, так и другой. Он представляет собой совершенно новую ревизию. И даже в том случае, когда участие пользователя в самом объединении веток не требуется, от него всё равно требуется получить подтверждение после того, как будет получен окончательный вариант новой ревизии. Именно для этого и нужен commit после merge. Если объединение прошло на автомате, то commit играет лишь роль подтверждения, которое необходимо для фиксации любой ревизии в репозитории.

Comment: - Неплохо написано, но результат объединения двух веток может оказывать влияние только на одну из этих веток, вторая же ветка всегда остается без изменений. Это верно как для `svn merge,` так и для `svn merge --reintegrate`.